# limiting the log-likelihood function for Weibull distribution

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ be random samples from the Weibull distribution $\operatorname{Weibull}(\alpha,1), \alpha >0$. Prove that the solution of the likelihood equation $\dot{l}(\alpha)=0$ is the MLE for $\alpha$.

Here is my attempt:

Since
$f(x;\alpha)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\exp{(-x^{\alpha})}I_{x>0}$
,
$$l(\alpha)=n\log{\alpha}+(\alpha-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\log{x_{i}}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^\alpha}$$
$$\dot{l}(\alpha)=\frac{n}{\alpha}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\log{x_{i}}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^\alpha \log{x_{i}}}$$
$$\ddot{l}(\alpha)=-\frac{n}{\alpha ^2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^\alpha( \log{x_{i}})^2}<0$$

Therefore, $l(\alpha)$ is a concave function.

Meanwhile,
$$\lim_{\alpha→+\infty}{l(\alpha)}=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{\alpha→+0}{l(\alpha)}=-\infty$$

Therefore, there exists a unique solution to the equation $\dot{l}(\alpha)=0$, which is the MLE for $\alpha$.

I know that I can solve the problem in this way, but I'm struggling with proving that
$$\lim_{\alpha→+\infty}{l(\alpha)}=-\infty$$
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of convenience, let $$\xi = \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i = \log \prod_{i=1}^n x_i, \quad g(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha; \tag{1}$$ then $$\ell(\alpha) = n \log \alpha + (\alpha - 1) \xi - g(\alpha). \tag{2}$$

Now by the AM-GM inequality (since $x_1, \ldots, x_n > 0$),
$$g(\alpha) \ge n \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha\right)^{1/n} = n e^{\xi \alpha/n}. \tag{3}$$  So $$\ell(\alpha) \le n \log \alpha + (\alpha-1)\xi - n e^{\xi \alpha/n}. \tag{4}$$  We easily see that for $n > 0$, $\ell(\alpha) \to -\infty$ as $\alpha \to 0^+$ irrespective of $\xi$.

If $\xi > 0$, then the last term in $(4)$ dominates, and $\ell(\alpha) \to -\infty$ as $\alpha \to \infty$.  If $\xi < 0$, then the second term dominates and again the log-likelihood approaches $-\infty$.  The only case in which the inequality $(4)$ is inconclusive is if $\xi = 0$.  So we return to $(2)$ and compute

$$\ell(\alpha \mid \xi = 0) = n \log \alpha - g(\alpha). \tag{5}$$  Let $x_{(n)} = \max_i x_i$ be the maximum order statistic.  If $x_{(n)} > 1$, then $$g(\alpha) > x_{(n)}^\alpha \to \infty$$ as $\alpha \to \infty$, and this term dominates in $(5)$.  The case $x_{(n)} < 1$ is impossible because $\xi = 0$ implies $e^\xi = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ hence there must be at least one $x_i$ whose value is at least $1$.  The final case, $\xi = 0$ and $x_{(n)} = 1$, implies $x_i = 1$ for all $i$, thus $g(\alpha) = n$ and $$\ell(\alpha \mid \xi = 0, g = n) = n (-1 + \log \alpha), \tag{6}$$ which does not have a global maximum since in this situation $\ell'(\alpha) = n/\alpha$ which has no critical point.  However, such a sample occurs with probability $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is about the sufficiency of the solution to the first order condition with respect to the global optimization problem.

As you showed that the log-likelihood function is strictly concave, any solution for first order condition, that is $\alpha: \dot l(\alpha)=0$ is indeed a strict (unique) global maximum. I don't see what more you need to prove. This is a well known result from optimization theory.

But to actually find this optimal $\alpha$, you will need a numerical method, as closed form solutions are not available in this case.

Comment: I need to prove that the existence of the solution to the $\dot{l}(\alpha)=0$ as well, because being concave doesn't guarantee the existence of maximum ($\log{x}$?).

Comment: Look at the statement in the question you presented: "Prove that the solution of the likelihood equation $\dot l(\alpha)=0$ is the MLE for $\alpha$".  It is not asking you to prove the existence of the solution, but to prove that if the solution to $\dot l(\alpha)=0$ exists then it is MLE for $\alpha$.

Comment: Maybe that's a translation problem... The original problem is not in English and I couldn't think of a proper translation for it. But initially it is not asking to prove that "if the solution to l˙(α)=0 exists then it is MLE for α". Proving the existence of the solution is also a part of the problem.

Comment: Even if proving the existence of the solution is not what the problem is asking, I'm still curious about how to prove it.

Comment: I believe that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow +0} \dot l(\alpha)=+\infty$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%28log%28a*x%5E%28a-1%29*exp%28-x%5Ea%29%29%2Ca%2C0%29